# Is there a way to tell whether an instance of MediaCodec has been configured successfully?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

Suppose a method obtains an instance of MediaCodec, is there a way for it to check whether this MediaCodec has been configured successfully?

For example, the MediaCodec is supposed to be configured as following:

```
myMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormatFoo, surfaceFoo, null, 0);
```

The above statement could fail and generate an exception, but the method does not have this knowledge. The only thing it has is a reference to the MediaCodec.

Comment: If you call that, and it doesn't throw an exception, you can assume that it has been configured successfully.  I'm not sure what you mean by "the method does not have this knowledge".

Comment: To simplify the story, let us just suppose that I am writing the code for a method of a library called methodFoo(MediaCodec mediaCodec) that does something with mediaCodec.  How can the method determine whether that mediaCodec has been configured properly so that it can go ahead to perform a bunch of tasks with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaCodec Java implementation provides a thin wrapper around the (non-public) MediaCodec C++ implementation, which provides a minimal inter-process wrapper around the OMX API, which is what the codecs implement.  The key concept being "minimal".

I think you're stuck with documenting that the method takes a configured MediaCodec as an argument, and explaining that the behavior will be undefined if it isn't.  It's the caller's responsibility to not call your method.

You may wish to consider doing the configuration within your library and passing a wrapper object back (e.g. "ConfiguredMediaCodec") that has the MediaCodec instance as a non-public member; whether or not this makes sense depends on the nature of your library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. In other words, MediaCodec itself does not offer anything to confirm whether it has been configured or its configuration has been successful. This is all I need to know.  I can catch the exception in the method if it has not been configured successfully.